# error TS2351: This expression is not constructable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to develop a chatbot. Please have a look below to see where I'm going wrong

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Pusher from 'pusher-js';

// this is here to discourage the instantianting of pusher any where its
// needed, better to reference it from one place
@Injectable()
export class PusherService {
private _pusher: any;

constructor() {
  this._pusher = new Pusher ('APP_KEY', {
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
  });
}

getPusher() {
  return this._pusher;
}

}
```

Comment: this question missing information needed to provide an answer – why do you say things are "going wrong"? does nothing happen when you run the code? do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `import *` imports the *whole namespace*. To access its default export, you'd have to use `Pusher.default`. But unless you need the whole namespace, how about just importing the class?

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
```

as [the docs recommend](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#nodejs).